# How to show $\int_0^\infty Vol( \{x\in M : \phi(x)\ge t \} \cap M) dt =\int_M \phi $?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

$M$ is a open set of $R^n$ with regular boundary . $\phi :M \rightarrow R^+$ is smooth function . How to show 
$$
\int_0^\infty Vol( \{x\in M : \phi(x)\ge t \}  \cap  M) dt =\int_M \phi   
$$

Comment: This is a standard fact of measure theory. Look up for "layer cake formula" in the book "Analysis" by Lieb and Loss

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple consequence of Tonelli theorem. I denote $Vol$ by $\mu$
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \mu( \{x\in M : \phi(x)\ge t \}  \cap  M) dt 
&=\int_0^\infty \mu( \{x\in M : \phi(x)\ge t \} ) dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty \int \chi_{\{x\in M : \phi(x)\ge t \}}(y) d\mu(y) dt \\
&= \int \int_0^\infty \chi_{\{x\in M : \phi(x)\ge t \}}(y) dt d\mu(y) \\
&= \int \int_0^\infty \chi_{M}(y) \chi_{[0,\phi(y)]}(t) dt d\mu(y)\\
&= \int \chi_{M}(y) \int_0^\infty\chi_{[0,\phi(y)]}(t) dt d\mu(y)\\
&= \int \chi_{M}(y) \phi(y) d\mu(y)\\
&= \int_M \phi(y) d\mu(y)
\end{align}$$